# Windows Metro Store App TextBox Disable Style XAML

Tags: styles, winrt-xaml

I have TextBox once I make it to IsEnable=false my TextBox is not visible so how I do style to make it as it is I have removed Disable state from style but still same problem.

my style is here.

```
        <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextSelectionHighlightColorThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>

                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="&#xE0A4;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBackgroundThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource TextControlPointerOverBorderThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="BackgroundElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderElement" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundHeaderThemeBrush}" FontWeight="Semilight" Margin="0,4,0,4" Grid.Row="0"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" IsTabStop="False" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextBoxPlaceholderTextThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" IsTabStop="False" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

check attach Image when I am making it to IsEnable=false.
[image]

How do I make it as a normal.

Comment: Your Style works fine, what Background color (on the Page) do you have?

Comment: I am using background color for this page. is "#f2f2f2"

Comment: Do you override somewhere "TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" or "TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush"?

Comment: No, I don't override "TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush" or "TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush"

Comment: Then I need to see the whole picture as your code looks fine for me. Can you upload your project somewhere?

Comment: Hi Dani, you can download code from here. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DCB3B50112850CA8!5188&authkey=!AIHDibv9sxbTV9U&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Now I'm a little bit confused. I can see your disabled TextBox even though it's grey in grey. If you add <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush" Color="Yellow"/> to your Page Resource you can see a yellow border if the TextBlox is disabled.